# How to Identify the elements which are removed from set() in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, python-3.x, set

I tried using `set()` method of python to find the unique elements in the List. It works fine removing all the duplicates. But here is my requirement, I want to get the elements which are removed by using `set()` method. Could any one please assist me in this?

```
a=[1,2,3,1,4]
b=set(a)
Output:[1,2,3,4]
```

My expected output is `[1]`.The element which is removed from the `set()` method

Comment: What if the input is `[1,2,3,1,4, 1, 1]`?

Comment: Get their count and check the items with count > 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend Set class(have your own Set class say MySet) and override this function

```
def _update(self, iterable):
    # The main loop for update() and the subclass __init__() methods.
    data = self._data

    # Use the fast update() method when a dictionary is available.
    if isinstance(iterable, BaseSet):
        data.update(iterable._data)
        return

    value = True

    if type(iterable) in (list, tuple, xrange):
        # Optimized: we know that __iter__() and next() can't
        # raise TypeError, so we can move 'try:' out of the loop.
        it = iter(iterable)
        while True:
            try:
                for element in it:
                    data[element] = value
                return
            except TypeError:
                transform = getattr(element, "__as_immutable__", None)
                if transform is None:
                    raise # re-raise the TypeError exception we caught
                data[transform()] = value
    else:
        # Safe: only catch TypeError where intended
        for element in iterable:
            try:
                data[element] = value
            except TypeError:
                transform = getattr(element, "__as_immutable__", None)
                if transform is None:
                    raise # re-raise the TypeError exception we caught
                data[transform()] = value
```

Comment: Yes because that's what the question was. For those who have used Counter I believe you have given an alternative rather than replying to what was asked (with extra loops etc) Thanks for the down vote btw :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need set.  You want a count of each element with more than one occurrence.  Counter from collections together with a dictionary comprehension should get you there.

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]    
removed = {k: v-1 for k, v in Counter(a).iteritems() if v > 1}

>>> removed
Out[8]: {1: 2, 2: 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is useful here.

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(a)
b = set(counts.keys())
for x, count in counts.items():
    if count > 1:
        print('%d appearances of %s were removed in the set' % (count-1, x))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this with `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
a = [1, 2, 3, 1, 4]
>>>[i for i in Counter(a) if Counter(a)[i] > 1]
[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return a set containing only the items removed from your original set:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 5]

>>> set(i for i in a if a.count(i) > 1)

>>> {1}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're approaching the problem in a slightly conflated way.  Rather than trying to get a `set()` to do something it's not intended to do (return a list of duplicates) I would use a `collections.Counter()` to gather up the duplicates and then get the set from that.

Here's some code:

```
#!python
from collections import Counter
c = Counter([1,2,3,1,4])
dupes = [k for k,v in c.items() if v>1]
b = set(c.keys())
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple python example,

```
def finder(s):
    seen,yields=set(),set()
    for i in s:
      if i in seen and i not in yields:
          yield i
          yields.add(i)
      else:
          seen.add(i)
    print(type(seen), seen )
    
a = [1,2,3,1,4] 
print(list(finder(a)))
```

produces,

```
<class 'set'> {1, 2, 3, 4}
[1]

[Program finished]
```